# open HTML content in android tablet in web view

Tags: android

i want to open HTML page in my web view using loadURL() method ..its Home page is opening now only and other link on click of button is not working..while when i open it my Browser its working fine so pls suggest me what strategy should i follow..is it possible in android tabs as it is opening in IPad ..my code is below pls refer..

```
    package OpenHtml.pkg;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 public class OpenHtml extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    try {
        InputStream fin = getAssets().open("index.html");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
            fin.read(buffer);
            fin.close();
            webview.loadUrl("@@@@@@");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check is it require INTERNET connection or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

hii shyam i show the html content in my webview by following code.
I am sure it will help you.

```
    WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.comment_webview);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("your url");
```

Make sure you have defined internet permission in your manifest file.
If it workde please vote